# Google Sheets embed: Broken page in mobile browsers

Tags: ios, mobile, google-sheets

I am embeding Google Sheets via `iframe` using url that I can get from the Share dialog but the footer with sheet list is broken. See image below:

[image]

This is from Develop menu in desktop Safari, but the same things happen in Safari on iOS and apparently other mobile browsers.

The page below is local HTML that has no extra styles or HTML elements apart from the `iframe` that is hosting this embed.

Did I miss some extra setting required for embed?

EDIT: Still happening after months so probably not some random glitch in Google Sheets.

Comment: What do you mean by its broken? Is it that the rest of the information is not showing or some pages are not showing? please be specific, I have seen the image but do not understand you.

Comment: @mw509 the "List 1" button and the whole toolbar should be at the bottom and not interfere with content. Similar when you are using Google Sheets outside of iframe embed

Comment: Its weird cos I published a document and iframed it. it showed just fine with content. Can you reproduce a little part of the code you are using here or somewhere so I can help.

Comment: https://daffy-deserted-sphynx.glitch.me/ check this glitch. If you open it on a mobile device or simulate mobile device in your browser, the layout is broken...

Answer (score 3):

You're getting the link from the wrong place. Don't use the link from the **Share** dialog or anywhere else.

Get it from **File > Publish to the web**. That will give you an iframe embed code.

[image]

Comment: This answer is the best way to achieve what you want to do. Google does not allow for editing files anywhere other than through the google sheets app itself. So you can always make changes at the original file and the iframe embed code will be for viewing only.